# How to ensure unicorn disconnects ALL DB connections in rails 6.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6, unicorn, ruby-on-rails-6.1

In unicorn.rb it's common to have clauses like this:

```
before_fork do |server, worker|
  # Disconnect since the database connection will not carry over
  if defined? ActiveRecord::Base
    ActiveRecord::Base.clear_all_connections!
  end
end
```

To ensure db connections are closed when reloading the app. Since the introduction of "roles" and "shards" in Rails I am unsure how I would make sure that ALL connections/pools are disconnected, not only the ["current role" one](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/83217025a171593547d1268651b446d3533e2019/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb#L1096)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I think I found it...

```
before_fork do |server, worker|
  # Disconnect since the database connection will not carry over
  if defined? ActiveRecord::Base
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_handlers.each do |role, handler|
      Rails.logger.info("Clearing/closing all connections for #{role} role...")
      handler.clear_all_connections!
    end
  end
end
```